# Create a Jira Issue with custom Field name by using atlassian SDK

Tags: c#, jira, atlassian-plugin-sdk

Through C# I am trying to create Jira issue which has custom field "Selling Details" using `Atlassian SDk`. Below is the code:

```
  string username = "XXX";
        string password = "XXX";
        string url = "https://rajasekharjira.atlassian.net";


        var settings = new JiraRestClientSettings()
        {
            EnableRequestTrace = true
        }; 
        settings.CustomFieldSerializers.Add("https://rajasekharjira.atlassian.net", new SingleObjectCustomFieldValueSerializer("Selling Details"));



        var jira = Jira.CreateRestClient(url, username, password,settings);
        var issue = jira.CreateIssue("GUID");
        issue.Type = "Bug";
        issue.Priority = "High";
        issue.Summary = "Issue Summary";
        issue.CustomFields["Selling Details"].Values[0] = "abc";

        issue.SaveChanges();

 public class SingleObjectCustomFieldValueSerializer : ICustomFieldValueSerializer
{
    //public string[] FromJson(JToken json)
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}

    //public JToken ToJson(string[] values)
    //{
    //    throw new NotImplementedException();
    //}
    private readonly string _propertyName;

    public SingleObjectCustomFieldValueSerializer(string propertyName)
    {
        this._propertyName = propertyName;
    }

    public string[] FromJson(JToken json)
    {
        return new string[1] { json[this._propertyName].ToString() };
    }

    public JToken ToJson(string[] values)
    {
        return new JObject(new JProperty(this._propertyName, values[0]));
    }
}
```

i am getting error at: `issue.CustomFields["Selling Details"].Values[0] = "abc";`

So please let me know how to create the issue with **custom field name**

I had updated the code  with Serializer but i am not getting the custom fields at **issue.CustomFields["Selling Details"].Values[0] = "abc";**

Comment: Have you created the Serialiser as per this - https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Custom%20Fields?

Comment: Hi i had added the Serialiser as you said

Comment: I had updated the post with Serialiser  code please refresh the page and see. @shree.pat

Comment: Can any one help on this

Answer (score 3):

The way that is trying to access into a custom field is wrong, it just needs to use the brackets and the name of the custom field to get into it.

Instead of:

```
issue.CustomFields["Selling Details"].Values[0] = "abc";
```

use:

```
issue["Selling Details"] = "abc";
```

Comment: Please explain why this change solves the problem to improve the longterm value of your answer.